# image slider title not properly aligned

Tags: css, image, slider, title

Can anyone figure out why the title on this image slider will not align properly? I want it to be he same length as the image. Currently, the left side is too long.

Also, the title is too short as the image fades in but then corrects itself to be the proper length. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the url for the page: http://homepages.uc.edu/~daniela8/slider/slider4/slider4.html

Here is the css for the title:

```
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title{
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left: 32px;
margin-right:5px;
z-index: 50;
background-color:#000000;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:10px 1%;
width:78%;
font-family: "Myriad Pro", Arial, "Franklin Gothic Medium";
font-size: 14px;
opacity:0.55;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=55); 
}
#wowslider-container1 .ws-title div{
padding-top:5px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
left: 32px;
width:78%;
```

reduce width, increase left margin

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @Kedar! If I reduce the width, it changes the entire image, making it all smaller, which is not what I want. Also, when I increase the left margin, the title moves over so that it's overlapping the image on both sides. The problem, I think is what @John_C said about the image padding, but I can't figure out what to change to make it work. Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I could come up with:

```
.ws-title {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 54px;
    padding-right: 54px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I tested it and the above code seems to have aligned the caption. You can experiment more by changing the value of `padding-left` and `padding-right` as you need.

Comment: I added your code above into my css, but it did not affect anything. Can you tell me where you put it and if you changed or deleted any other code? Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can't tell what's wrong on your side, on my end it seems to work. Which browser are you using? I'm on Chrome. And do one thing, upload the source files somewhere publicly, on mediafire or some other service.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Sean Vaughn. I'm using Firefox and Safari to test it. Did you add the code above into the css or put it in place of one of the other two div id' above? Thanks!

Comment: I added the css code in the debug console of Google Chrome. There's no way to edit the source files other than that because they are on your server, that's why I asked you to upload it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the 2 earlier answers but I think the problem has its roots in the images themselves.
They all have a left margin of whitespace, e.g.;
http://homepages.uc.edu/~daniela8/slider/slider4/data1/images/frog.jpg

The title begins at the start of the image but the image itself has padding.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I've tried both adding and deleting the padding on css for the image's container and for the title and neither affected the title problem. Do you know what I should do to change the padding around the image? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not replying earlier. I think I wasn't fully clear in my answer yesterday. I meant that you should edit the images with some image editing software (photoshop, paint or similar) to remove the white space surrounding them. If that's not possible, adding 'width: 620px;left: 160px;' to the .ws-title should fix it but it's not the best solution since it depends on the formatting of the images. The style will need to be added inline since that's where the existing styling is.